# Iterate over a method for the given arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I've the following code-construct which I wish to simplify.

What the below code does is to call the `set` method of an object `myObject` with different parameters on the fly.

```
myObject.set("value1", 1);
myObject.set("value2", 1);
myObject.set("value3", 1);
myObject.set("value4", 12);
```

One option is to keep the values in an array, something like

```
var myArr = [["value1",1], ["value2", 1], ["value3",1], ["value4", 12]];
```

and repeatedly call `myObject.set` for the size of the above array.

I was looking into simplying this by using `loadash` but couldn't find any suitable methods. (I tried `_.over` method but couldn't get this to work)

Any suitable ideas or methods in loadash ?

Comment: what is `myObject`? and how do you get the size of it by repeating calling `set`?

Comment: `myObject` is simply a javascript object which contains a function `set`. Now, I need to call this function 'set` of the `myobject` - for all elements in the array `myArr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the array and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the values (the sub array) when calling `set`:

```js
const myObject = { set: console.log };

const multiSet = arr => arr.forEach((v) => myObject.set(...v))

const arr = [["value1",1], ["value2", 1], ["value3",1], ["value4", 12]];

multiSet(arr);
```

With lodash/fp you generate a function that handles an array of arrays with `_.forEach()` and `_.spread()` (lodash also needs `_.partialRight()`):

```js
const { forEach, spread } = _;

const myObject = { set: console.log };

const multiSet = forEach(spread(myObject.set.bind(myObject))); // or lodash - partialRight(forEach, spread(myObject.set.bind(myObject)))

const arr = [["value1",1], ["value2", 1], ["value3",1], ["value4", 12]];

multiSet(arr);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Looks cool. Btw, can you please explain your `second line`. especially where you use `myObject.set(...v)`. why there are 3 dots?

Comment: The value is an `array[a, b]`, and you want to convert it to functions params `set(a, b)`. To do so, you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you actually want to achive but I think you are looking for the "Rest parameter"

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

example:

```
myObject.set = function(...theArgs){ 
    theArgs.forEach((argument) => {
         //Do your logic
         console.log(argument)
    })
}

myObject.set(["value1",1], ["value2", 1], ["value3",1], ["value4", 12])
```

Comment: well, good answer. but what about cases where you cannot modify `myobject.set`. may be think of that as an external library.

Comment: The name "myObject" suggests you made it yourself and have full controll over the logic/code. It's still not very clear where you are going to

Comment: For the purposes of simplification, I did that. I'm actually calling a method in an external library repeatedly for a set of varying parameters.

Comment: Then you should just go for Array.forEach()

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to call `myObject.set` with each item in `myArr`, you don't need lodash, you can use vanilla JavaScript

```
var myArr = [["value1",1], ["value2", 1], ["value3",1], ["value4", 12]];
myArr.forEach(args => myObj.set(args[0], args[1]))
```

Or if the parameters can vary, you can simply spread them:

```
myArr.forEach(args => myObj.set(...args))
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write your `set` function in such a way that it handles multiple types of arguments. Just for the sake of flexibility

```
function MyObject() {
  this.map = {};
}

MyObject.prototype.set = function() {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  // var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(args[i])) {
      this.map[args[i][0]] = args[i][1];
    } else {
      this.map[args[i]] = !Array.isArray(args[i+1]) ? args[i++] : undefined;
    }
  }
}

MyObject.prototype.get = function() {
  console.log(this.map);
}

var myObject = new MyObject();


myObject.set("value1", 1, ['value2', 2], 'value3', ['value4', 4]);
console.log(myObject.get());
```